# Add values to User Meta Field within an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I want to have the following database entry for a User Meta Field:

```
meta_key => array ('value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3')
```

I tried to create the User Meta Field by the first push:

```
update_user_meta(
$user->id,
    meta_key,
    array ($value1)
);
```

Now I want to add new values to the array. But i don't want to lose the first. How is that possible?
add_user_meta is not working because it adds new database-entries all the time.

Comment: Hi.  Can you please revise your sample code - it doesn't actually make sense.  Can you use working code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you've shared is a bit mysterious, but I will do my best to give you an answer.

Conceptually, you'll just want to *get* the meta first, update it, then rewrite it.

So, once your meta values are written, when you want to update, you would do something like so:

```
// Lets create a reusable function for simplicity
/*
 * @param int $user id
 * @param string $meta_key
 * @param string $new_value - the new value to be added to the array
 */
function my_meta_update($user_id, $meta_key, $new_value) {
    // Get the existing meta for 'meta_key'
    $meta = get_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key, false);
    // Do some defensive coding - if it's not an array, set it up
    if ( ! array($meta) ) {
        $meta = array();
    }
    // Push a new value onto the array
    $meta[] = $new_value;
    // Write the user meta record with the new value in it
    update_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key, $meta);
}
```

Then you could updated user meta using that function like so:

```
// Add the "Value 2" to the array of meta values for user 1
my_meta_update(1, 'my_meta_key', 'Value 2');
```

**bonus**
At the request of OP, here's a method to remove a value:

```
/**
 * @param int $user_id
 * @param string $meta_key
 * @param string $remove_value - the value to remove from the array
 */
function my_meta_remove($user_id, $meta_key, $remove_value) {
    $meta = get_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key, false);
    // Find the index of the value to remove, if it exists
    $index = array_search($remove_value, $meta);
    // If an index was found, then remove the value
    if ($index !== FALSE) {
        unset($meta[$index]);
    }
    // Write the user meta record with the removed value
    update_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key, $meta);
}
```

Usage:

```
// Remove "Value 2" from the array of meta values for user 1
my_meta_remove(1, 'my_meta_key', 'Value 2');
```

Comment: Is it possible to delete single values of the array as well?

Comment: Certainly.  I'll update the answer to include delete as well.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the answer of @cale_b, I had to modify the code a little bit to make it work. Maybe an update since the answer is from 2015:

```
// Do some defensive coding - if it's not an array, set it up
if ( ! is_array($meta) ) {
    $meta = array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found with these functions that they repeatedly nested arrays rather than just having one main array with your values.

This is fixed with the following:

```
function my_meta_update($user_id, $meta_key, $new_value) {
    // Get the existing meta for 'meta_key'
    $meta = get_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key, true);
    // Do some defensive coding - if it's not an array, set it up
    if($meta == '') {
        $meta = array();
    }
    // Push a new value onto the array
    array_push($meta, $new_value);
    // Write the user meta record with the new value in it
    update_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key, $meta);
}

function my_meta_remove($user_id, $meta_key, $remove_value) {
    $meta = get_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key, true);
    // Find the index of the value to remove, if it exists
    $index = array_search($remove_value, $meta);
    // If an index was found, then remove the value
    if ($index !== FALSE) {
        unset($meta[$index]);
    }
    // Write the user meta record with the removed value
    update_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key, $meta);
}
```

With the main difference being `get_user_meta` set to true:

```
$meta = get_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key, true);
```